# Looking for an Microcontroller with H.264 hardware decoder

Tags: video, microcontroller

I'm trying to make a wireless VR headsetst. Looking for an MCU or an SOC that is capable of decoding the following video stream in realtime.

- H.264 Video codec,
- constant bit rate,
  500mbps.
- 120 frames per second.
- Resolution 2560x2560

Decoding latency should be 15ms per frame or less.

The SOC will receive the video stream over WiFi 6E (6GHZ band) and eventually send those pixels ton an LCD display for the final rendering, but that is a problem for another day. This post is exclusively dedicated
to the video decoder.

If an SOC does not exist a dedicated hardware decoder Thant can interface with an LCD also works for me.

Money is not a concern.

Extra points if you can provide a link to purchase a development board or the part in question.